# FOR LOOP with SQL Query Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not a `SQL` expert but on occasion I run into situations where I need a for loop to iterate over the results of a query into another query. Example:

```
SELECT values FROM some_table WHERE name="blah";
```

Or in bash I might do:

```
mysql -e "use ${database}; SELECT values FROM some_table WHERE name='blah';" > list
```

Then I wind up taking the result of this query into a file and formatting it to use with `php` or `bash` like so:

```
for i in `cat list`; do mysql -e "use ${database}; UPDATE other_table SET column="data" where values="${i}"; done
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with `SQL` and save me time of making and formatting the list file? I guess I would need to store the results of the first query in an array and then loop through it?

--Just to clarify I'm wanting to avoid using `bash`, `php`, or any other language and get done what I'm trying to do on the `mysql` "interactive" command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to update the other_table for all of the values which are present in some_table.?

You can accomplish that using

```
update other_table
   set column="data"
 where values in (select values from some_table where name='blah')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but, I think a subselect might be what you want.

```
  Select tableb.fieldname1
     from tableb
   where tableb.fieldname2 in
   (select tablea.fieldnamec
      from tablea
     where tablea.fieldnamed = 'blah'
   );
```